# What's the name of this type of acrylic?

Tags: material-selection, plastic, acrylic-glass

I recently came across [Love Hulton](http://www.lovehulten.com/buydatorbox.html)'s amazing work and was especially impressed by the aesthetic of the pearly acrylic front of the [datorbox](http://www.lovehulten.com/uploads/3/0/4/8/30489724/a3_orig.jpg). I saw the same material being used for fashioning guitar pickguards but could not find any information on it based on what came to my mind in an attempt to describe it.

What is the proper name of this type of acrylic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did a quick search for "pearlescent acrylic sheet" and it appears there is at least one resource for this type of product. Various contours and colors are available from [Acrilex](http://www.acrilex.com/product-category/pearlescent-acrylic-sheet/) and they all look quite fabulous!

[image: acrilex sample 01]

[image: acrilex sample 02]

[image: acrilex sample 03]

I didn't capture all 44 available patterns and there is at least one that resembles the panel in the photo you've linked.

I found a couple other resources, but the images were not as suitable nor as attractive as these samples. I might have a new resource for my laser cutter now!